# Yii2: how to write logs in file while testing with Codeception?

Tags: php, logging, yii2, codeception

I had set up `log` component with `FileTarget` in the main config and expected `Yii::error()` will write messages in the file when I will launch tests. But logging was catched up by `Codeception\Lib\Connector\Yii2\Logger` and log folder remains empty.

Is it possible to make Yii2 write logs in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure correct logger before test:

```
public function testSomething() {
    Yii::setLogger(Yii::createObject(\yii\log\Logger::class));
    Yii::$app->log->setLogger(Yii::getLogger());
    // log something
    Yii::getLogger()->flush();
    // test log file
}
```

Comment: Seems it has no effect, I don't see any changes in log files

Comment: Where do you put this? I've tried in the code, inside the test file and nothing is logged.

Comment: Can you provide some more info / a better answer? Plleeaseeeeeeee

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

namespace tests;

class SomeTest extends \yii\codeception\TestCase
{

    public function testLogMessage()
    {
        \Yii::error('something bad occurred');
    }

}
```

And this correctly logs error under runtime/log/app.log with message:

2018/05/05 03:42:04 [127.0.0.1] [error] [application] something bad occurred

Comment: Ok but I don't need to use Yii::error in test methods, I need to test code which uses Yii::error.